# How ISP track the individual subscriber data download and falling back to lower mbps?

Tags: qos, bandwidth, isp

I work on software development for routers. So, I am aware of QoS in routers, where we can do scheduling and policing of the traffic.

However, one question is still in my mind, is how does the ISP track how much data is downloaded by a subscriber, since there are so many subscribers, and they all will be connected with customer edge routers.

Next, once they reach their maximum limit of usage in terms of data download, how their internet speed is reduced. Like, do they enqueue into a queue of a router, which has lower priority. But, that will not restrict the lower speed always. Do they put an egress interface, whose port speed is less?

I am asking this for a normal use case where ISP will be running IS-IS or OSPF protocol as IGP and BGP to connect to other ISP.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

So, there are a few different methods that can be used to achieve this, but I'll stick to the ones I am familiar with.

In a PPPoE(oA) environment (e.g.: xDSL), each subscriber is tracked via a dedicated logical interface on the router, which keeps track of bytes in/bytes out and can have policers applied individually depending on usage.

In environments using IPoE (e.g.: users are tracked via DHCP), similar rules apply - logical subscriber interfaces are created in response to DHCP transactions (e.g.: a logical interface is created per IP address), and then filters are applied to these when these interfaces exceed bandwidth quotas.

In more simplistic environments, I have also seen bandwidth tracked using NetFlow/SFlow and then dedicated policers applied based on IP Address, however these generally don't scale particularly well.

Both of these methods require routers that support hierarchical queueing mechanisms - e.g.: they are able to queue per subscriber (IP Address), rather than just per sub interface (VLAN) or physical interface.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there usually are too many subscribers in any ISP's network for their routers to be able to do full analysis and shaping on them. If they had routers with more juice, they would have even more subscribers! ;) That's where Deep Packet Inspection comes into play.

(I've never worked for any ISP, but I have been deep into DPI for years, during which I worked with all kinds of service providers, starting from small university campus networks, through small (~1000 subs) local ISPs, up to national cable providers and mobile operators with 1M+ subscribers. Just saying.)

As to the first two OSI layers, we usually sit inline somewhere in customer's network aggregation point, on any copper or fibre links. Throughput-wise we can usually handle about 500 Gbps per a fully juiced chassis. Works best if you put your DPI engine somewhere next to, or between two edge routers. This way we're seeing all traffic before it hits NAT or firewalls. From there on it's all about the logic in the engine and configuration.

Starting at the very basics, your public IP (or any external IP of your CPE) is the number one identifier in any small cable network. University campus networks, or ISPs who know your CPE MAC address, or deliver the CPE themselves, recognise your MAC address the moment you come on the network with a first DHCP request, and can from then provision this information to the engine so that you're recognised as a subscriber no matter what IP you receive. Easy stuff.

Things are usually a little bit trickier when you are a mobile network operator. In it, the DHCP leases are much shorter, change often, and come from a lot of different locations and directions in the network. In such case you usually connect to an external provisioning system, using RADIUS feed or DHCP snooper to react when a subscriber comes up online or disconnects. It may take up to a few seconds, but we usually recognise you within the first few kilobytes of your presence on the net. We can even slow you down to a lower throughput rate until we recognise you as a valid subscriber.

There are some more complex networks, for example with multiple VLANs with overlapping local IPs. Our engine can be configured to recognise subscribers by VLAN+IP pair, or by any other mean - L2TP tunnel ID, MPLS label + local IP, and so on.

This way we can really recognise every subscriber in real time. And since we have some good CPUs in the house and a lot of memory, we can do some great stuff like shaping of throughput, packets or connection rates per second.

[Before you shout at me for net neutrality, allow me to explain how there's good and bad shaping in networks. I agree that providers allowing some apps paid "fast lanes" is bad shaping. So is the manner in which VoIP applications are controlled and blocked often in countries east of Africa. However, tell an ISP with 1000 customers and 10 Gbps uplink he cannot shape, and you will run him down right out of business. Allow him to do fair sharing of the link between hosts on the network, or shape total BitTorrent in the network to some reasonable values, and all his customers could happily use their net to the max without any real problems. Give Skype and gaming a little higher priority, and never again hear complaints about lagging network. Seriously. We literally had customers calling us up after we've deployed shaping on their links, thanking us for improving their QoE without adding any throughput capabilities to their network.]

As to how shaping works, there's two ways of doing it. One is to modify and control TCP window sizes, so services like HTTP downloads don't send too many bytes per second. However, this only works for TCP traffic and is not very clean, since it's rewriting packets on the fly. A lot better solution is queueing packets and TXing them out in a controlled manner, or dropping them if the shaping queues get too close to the configured maximum.

What specifically happens inside a DPI engine is a secret of each company, so I can't talk too much about that. I can tell you that at its base we usually use our own implementations of known algorithms, like Blue (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_(queue_management_algorithm)). The way these work is they queue packets and start buffering them even before the maximum throughput is reached, to be able to react to any bursts of traffic on the link. It's more heuristic than just dropping excess traffic, so I recommend you give it a wider read if you're interested.

Finally, I've never seen two ISPs doing any real shaping on the link between their edge routers. I would expect the respected practice would be each one of them sticks to not exceeding the link speed towards their neighbour. Unless you know examples of such practice? I'd be curious to learn the details.